# Poweredge 6800 operating system

Tags: dell-poweredge

Can I put Ubuntu 14.04 LOS on this?  Dell site says only Windows 2003 server?  KVM board blocks any upgrades by blocking the USB and CDROM device from working?

Comment: You should rephrase your question. I have no idea what you are asking. Can you put Ubuntu on a PE6800? I'm sure you can. But is that your actual question?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can install a modern OS on this server. It's just about the oldest system that would support a 64-bit OS. (Intel 7100-series CPUs, I presume?)

Now, is it *worth* using this system? **Not from a heat, power, noise or space/footprint perspective.** But if you have it and *want* to use it... sure, ***go nutty!!***

Ubuntu should install without issue or the need for additional drivers. Granted, [you may not be able to get the OMSA driver suite to work on Ubuntu](http://linux.dell.com/repo/hardware/omsa.html#Supported_Operating_Systems) for management/monitoring purposes.

As for your KVM board, reset the BIOS settings to default or use an external USB CD or network installer for Ubuntu... I don't see why that would be a problem for you. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

The *supported* operating systems are:

> Microsoft® Windows ServerTM 2003, Standard x64 Edition;
>   Microsoft Windows Server 2003, Enterprise x64 Edition;
>   Microsoft Windows Server 2003, Standard Edition;
>   Microsoft Windows Server 2003, Enterprise Edition;
>   Red Hat® Enterprise Linux® 3 and 4;
>   SUSE® Linux Enterprise Server 9 EM64T SP2

Everything on this list is end of life, or shortly to be end of life.

You're on your own for installing any other OS. (And if you want to ask a question about that, you need to specifically ask about it and provide a lot of detail.)

My recommendation would be to put this beast back in the dumpster that it came out of.

Comment: Well...yes I was aware of supported operating systems.  Dell denied my transfer of ownerhip request anyways.  Even though I bought it legitimately off of Craigslist.

I've made some hardware upgrades and think it may work with Ubuntu.   But I can't do anything if I don't solve the KVM problem.

Comment: Why would they transfer an ancient hardware system, where they don't sell support anymore anyways? And what KVM problem?

Comment: Dell's refusal to transfer ownership doesn't revoke your "ownership" of the equipment. Do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Thank you for the response.   I cannot get the Bios to recognize the USB or the CD/DVD Rom.  It will only boot to the KVM board's embedded NIC which connects to the previous owner's management console.  I cannot establish an Internet connection via that embedded NIC because I think it only communicates via SSH protocol.

Comment: @MichelZ The KVM problem is that it is the ONLY thing that boots via an embedded NIC and OS loading instructions from a previous management console.